# I have a data which are in different date time formats and i want them to convert them into same date time format

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

For Example

my current column data is

```
21-04-2022 14:30:00
02-03-2021 14:30:00
2021-05-02 14:30:00
2022-06-21 14:30:00
```

I want my data is same date time format.

```
2022-04-21 14:30:00
2021-03-02 14:30:00
2021-05-02 14:30:00
2022-06-21 14:30:00
```

I don't want changes in time but the thing is both date and time are in one column so i want a proper solution through which i can convert my data

i have tried different methods but nothing is helpful.

Comment: Column data type???

Comment: my column data type is varchar

Comment: Alter to proper data type, and your problem is solved. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to change the type of `varchar` to `datetime`
And then add the date with `INSERT INTO table Values('2022-04-21 14:30:00');`

In addition to the data you have already entered, **for example :**

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES('2022-04-21 14:30:00');
INSERT INTO table VALUES('2021-03-02 14:30:00');
INSERT INTO table VALUES('2021-05-02 14:30:00');
INSERT INTO table VALUES('2022-06-21 14:30:00');
```

**Note :** Where it says table add your table name